# Что такое удаление правки?

Tags: поддержка, предлагаемые-правки, правки

В действиях с [правкой](//ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/230248) моего вопроса увидел кнопку <kbd>Удалить</kbd>. Что она делает?

[image: скриншот]

> Принять, отклонить или улучшить правки, предложенные участниками.
>   (развернуть)
>
> - Принять
> - Улучшить правку
> - Отклонить и править
> - Отклонить
> - Удалить
> - Пропустить

Comment: Вероятно, это ["redact"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284114/2076787). Выжигает ревизию, не оставляя её даже в истории рассмотрений тех, кто по ней уже принял решение.